# CSV to JSON parsing creating an empty array

Tags: json

I'm very new to javascript (this is my first project) and I'm currently trying to parse a CSV file to a JSON. My current code looks like this:

```
document.getElementById("Import").onclick = async function importData() {
    const responce = await fetch('Books.csv') 
    const data = await responce.text()
    const rows = data.split('/n').slice(1)
    console.log(data)
    console.log(rows)
    for (let i = 0; i <= rows.length; i++){
        columns = rows[i].split(',').slice(0,3)
    }
    console.log(columns)
        for (let i = 0; i <= (columns.length)/4; i++){
            inventory[i] = {
                bookCode: columns(4*i),
                bookName: columns(4*i + 1),
                copies: columns(4*i + 2),
                borrowed: columns(4*i + 3)          
            }
        }
    
}
```

However the console shows rows as being an empty array. Could anyone please tell my why this is happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're splitting by the newline. The newline literal is \n, (your slash is the wrong way)

Comment: Thank you so much, just a quick follow up question if you don't mind. With the fix my console is now saying 'TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')' at line 8. Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: for (let i = 0; i <= rows.length; i++) should be for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++)

Javascript is 0 indexed not one indexed. 

So if you have an array that is length three, your indexes are 0,1,2 not 1,2,3